# Big-O of a recursive function

Tags: swift, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

just wondering, what's the big o of this function, 
let say the initial value of the parameters is as following:

```
numOfCourseIndex = 0
maximumScheduleCount = 1000
schedule = [[Section]]()
result = [[[Section]]]()
orderdGroupOfSections = n
```

.

```
func foo(numOfCourseIndex: Int, orderdGroupOfSections: [[[Section]]], maximumScheduleCount: Int) {


    if (result.count >= maximumScheduleCount) {
        return
    }

    for n in 0..<orderdGroupOfSections[numOfCourseIndex].count {
        for o in 0..<orderdGroupOfSections[numOfCourseIndex][n].count {
            for p in 0..<orderdGroupOfSections[numOfCourseIndex][n][o].sectionTime!.count {
                for q in 0..<orderdGroupOfSections[numOfCourseIndex][n][o].sectionTime![p].day!.count {

                   ///do something

               }
            }
        }

        if (numOfCourseIndex == orderdGroupOfSections.count - 1) {

          result.append(schedule)

        }
        else {
            foo(numOfCourseIndex: numOfCourseIndex + 1, orderdGroupOfSections: orderdGroupOfSections, maximumScheduleCount: maximumScheduleCount)
        }
    }      
}
```

I'm saying it's a Big-O of (n!) as the worst case, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What is your justification for it to be O(n!)? A description of what the code does would greatly help in analysing it.

Comment: I mean big O of (n!), sorry my mistake, my motivation is the number of the possible schedules is equal to **the multiplication of all array section count in the result array**

Comment: Don't just guess at it... you should be able to say *why* you think it's O(2^n) or O(n!) or whatever it turns out to be. What does `n` even represent here? It seems like the complexity depends on a number of different variables.

Comment: I think it is O(n^4)

Comment: Also, your example is incomplete. What do you define as n? How many entries are there in `orderdGroupOfSections`? (you can likely define it as `n` and don't care about the number of entries, unless it's static).

Comment: to justify my answer..  i.e  if first array in the result has 4 sections, and the second has 2 sections, the result will be 8

Comment: Will the arrays *always* have 4*2 entries? Also, please see mine and @Caleb's question about what`n` represents. Without respect of knowing what `n` is, it's literally impossible to tell what the time complexity is.

Comment: yes orderdGroupOfSections has n entries

Comment: And does the number of entries in `orderdGroupOfSections` (`n`) drop off or change between each recursion?

Comment: No, it doesn't change

Comment: In that case it's O(n^∞) without a proper edge condition. It's too messy to make a grasp of as it is now. You should edit your question and explain what your code does, either in comments or as a text.

Comment: why ? it stops the recursive call when it reaches to the last array of of the `orderdGroupOfSections`

Comment: It stops doing more recursive calls after n iterations (hence the n part) but the already spawned recursive calls will spawn n new recursions, which will spawn n new recursions, which will spawn n new recursions ... and so on, hence the ∞ part.

Comment: @Faisal But if I understand the `if` statement with a `return` correctly it will stop after `result` is filled with 1000 entries. If we call `maximumScheduleCount = m` I believe it should be O(n^m)

Comment: it's not ∞, I'm not sure how I can explain it, but think of it like a "Cartesian Product", basically what is happening is it tries every possible combination of schedules, in each call it take the first section and add it to the schedule,until it reaches the end of the result count, then add to `result` the schedules that has been generated,  then it goes back to the previous recursive call then add one to the counter n, which means it goes to the second section of the `orderdGroupOfSections - 2` (Before Last) then call a recursive call to try a different combination

Comment: it's not necessary to have `maximumScheduleCount`, it's for stopping the function from going to crazy numbers like 100k+ in the`result`.. but it will stop eventually

Comment: @Faisal In order to determine the time complexity you must define a clear edge condition and when that happen. The depth of the recursions must be clearly defined as well (like O(`log m`) or something). @Caleb have written a great explanation on what your focus should be. I recommend reading that and try to split the time complexity up to easier define your function.

Comment: @Faisal The problem is that your data structures are way to complicated to understand for someone who haven't written the code (nested arrays are always a hassle), since they seem to be dependent on structures outside the function that you want to determine the time complexity on.

Answer (score 1):

There are two simple things that you can do to help you analyze the complexity of your function. The first is to simplify the input and see how the function behaves. Instead of running the function for a large number of courses or schedules or whatever, look at what it does for just one. How many steps does it take to process one course? How many for two? Three? Four? Make a table with the results, and then look at the difference between one and two courses, two and three, three and four, etc. Can you see a pattern?

The second thing you can do is break the function down into parts and analyze the parts separately. You're probably not going to be able to just *see* the complexity of the whole thing because it's, well, *complex*. So simplify it... what's the complexity of the innermost loop? How about the second innermost loop, ignoring the innermost one? What's the complexity of the two together? Rinse and repeat.